# ReactJS: Uncheck previously checked checkbox when another checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have this code located in `Advanced.js`. It generates checkboxes.

```
<div>
    <h6>Sellers</h6>
    {
    data.data.map((item, i) => {
        return <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox" key={i}>
                 <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id={item.slug} name={item.slug} onClick={this.props.filterItems()}/>
                 <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor={item.slug}>{item.name}</label>
                </div>
    }) 
    }
</div>
```

and this is from the `index.js`.
I called `Advanced.js`: `<Advanced filterItems={() => this.getBrand}`

and this is the getBrand function:

```
getBrand = (e) => {
        var checked = !e ? false : e.target.checked
        var name = !e ? "" : e.target.name
        if(checked){
            this.setState({
                brands: name
            }, () => {
                this.filterSeller()
            })
        }else{
            this.setState({
                brands: ""
            }, () => {


    this.home()
        })
    }

}
```

what happens is that, when I check a checkbox and checked another, both of them are checked. like this:

[image]

What I want to happen is that, when I check another checkbox, the previously checked checkbox should become unchecked. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Use a controlled component: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use `radio-buttons` which are made exactly for this use case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio